# Accessing OneDrive doc of Personal Account or Only one user in Business account via API

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am able to access OneDrive items of all the users in Office 365 business account using a free trial created from this link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/business/office-365-enterprise-e3-business-software?rtc=1&activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab

However, in order to make it work I needed to give my application below permission, which eventually allows this app to access OneDrive items of all the users in this tenant because of these permissions.

**File.Read.All -> Delegate**

**File.Read.All -> Application**

**User.Read     -> Delegate**

**User.Read.All -> Delegate**

**Site.Read.All -> Delegate**

Now, my requirement is to access OneDrive document of only one users from this tenant and block the application from accessing documents from other users, or access document of any personal account (@hotmail.com/@live.com).

Please let me know if there is any way or in case I am doing anything wrong with the application I registered.

Asked the same question here but bot told to ask to azure team in stackoverflow
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1219

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to understand the differences between Application permission and Delegate permission.

Application permission means App-only, the application acts as a user but there is no user sign in.

Delegate permission means App + User, a user will need to log into the application and access the resources.

So based on the permissions you have provided, I can't tell if your application requires a user to log in. If yes, Delegate permissions will take effect. Based on [Delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-15), `Files.Read.All` allows the app to read all files the signed-in user can access. If the signed in user can access others' document, then your app can access them too. So if you control the access permissions for the user in OneDrive or SharePoint, your app with this signed in user will have the same permissions.

If your app doesn't require a signed in user, Application permissions will take effect in this case. Based on [Application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-15), `Files.Read.All` allows the app to read all files in all site collections without a signed in user. So this scenario does not meet your needs.

Comment: Thansk Allen for the reply, yeah I don't require user to sign in, so I guess there is no possibility to block application to read files of some of the users from tenant, right?

Comment: @kartikghodasara Sorry for the delay. But you are correct. Without user you can't control the app's permission.